# remove duplicate Data after Execute SelectQuery in mutliple Tables

Tags: java, mysql, sql

i have Three tables `[users,projects,scenarios]`  i need to get latest update projects details based on `modified Date` column with out duplicate values

the tables  are:

```
users Table :
```

[image]

```
project table
```

[image]

```
scenario Table
```

[image]

and  i try below query   but its return duplicates values if am using `group by` then old values  came but i need latest values

**With out Group by query**

```
SELECT
    p.`PROJECT_NAME`,
    p.`CREATED_DATE`,
    s.`MODIFIED_DATE`
FROM
    `projects` p
JOIN `scenarios` s ON
    s.`PROJECT_ID` = p.`PROJECT_ID`
WHERE
    P.`USER_ID` =(
    SELECT
        USER_ID
    FROM
        users
    WHERE
        EMAIL = 'test@gmail.com'
)
ORDER BY
    s.`MODIFIED_DATE`
DESC
```

**out put:**[image]

**with Group by Query :**

```
SELECT
    p.`PROJECT_NAME`,
    p.`CREATED_DATE`,
    s.`MODIFIED_DATE`
FROM
    `projects` p
JOIN `scenarios` s ON
    s.`PROJECT_ID` = p.`PROJECT_ID`
WHERE
    P.`USER_ID` =(
    SELECT
        USER_ID
    FROM
        users
    WHERE
        EMAIL = 'test@gmail.com'
)
group by p.PROJECT_NAME
ORDER BY
    s.`MODIFIED_DATE`
DESC
```

output:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separately get the latest scenario per project using a subquery then the resulting rows will then be join again to get the other columns, if needed.

```
SELECT  p.PROJECT_NAME,
        p.CREATED_DATE,
        s.MODIFIED_DATE
        -- all columns in s.* will have the latest row
FROM    projects p
        INNER JOIN scenarios s
            ON  p.PROJECT_ID = s.PROJECT_ID
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  project_ID, MAX(modified_date) MAX_modified_date
            FROM    scenarios
            GROUP   BY project_ID
        ) t ON s.project_ID = t.project_ID
                AND s.modified_date = t.MAX_modified_date
        INNER JOIN users u
            ON P.USER_ID = u.USER_ID
WHERE   u.EMAIL = 'test@gmail.com'
ORDER   BY s.MODIFIED_DATE DESC
```

However, if you don't need to get the other columns, you can directly use `MAX()` and `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT  p.PROJECT_NAME,
        p.CREATED_DATE,
        MAX(s.MODIFIED_DATE) AS MAX_MODIFIED_DATE
FROM    projects p
        INNER JOIN scenarios s
            ON  p.PROJECT_ID = s.PROJECT_ID
        INNER JOIN users u
            ON P.USER_ID = u.USER_ID
WHERE   u.EMAIL = 'test@gmail.com'
GROUP   BY p.PROJECT_NAME,
            p.CREATED_DATE
ORDER   BY MAX_MODIFIED_DATE DESC
```

Comment: two queries giving two different results  ...i think second query gives wrong data